# Is there any name for such kind of metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

Let $(\mathbb{D},d)$ be metric space and $f$ function from $\mathbb{D}$ to some arbitrary set. This metric has the property that if for all $x\in \mathbb{D}$ exists neighborhood of $x$ in which $f$ is constant then $f$ must be constant in $\mathbb{D}$. $\mathbb{R}$ is an example of such metric, while $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ doesn't satisfy this property (For example we may choose $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x>0\\ 0, x<0 \end{cases}$ )
I wonder if there is a name for such metrics.

Comment: This seems related to the connectedness property of the topological spaces. If the space is disconnected, then you will find a function which violates your desired property.

Comment: You are presumably forgetting to add the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @ajr Thank you, I took a look on a wikipedia page and it says that the property that I'm looking for is actually equivalent to connectivity.

Comment: @felipeh Continuity is not needed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I’m misunderstanding, I think the term you are looking for is *connected*.